# Form submission is not getting most recent data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a fully functioning set of forms below, with one exception. There seems to be an issue with the `checkForAirVsAirMods()` function. For some reason the form submission always contains the default data that is pre-filled from air_vs_air_mods.json. I need to use whatever is in the form at the time that the adjudicate button is pressed. It works fine for the other sections but not for t his one. Here is the full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   function populateDetails(data, target) {
       let html = '';
       for (let key in data) {
           if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== 'nomenclature') {
               html += `<label>${key}: <input type="text" name="${key}" value="${data[key]}" /></label><br>`;
           }
       }
       $(target).html(html).show();
   }


   function loadAircraftData(forceType) {
       $.getJSON("/static/" + forceType + "_aircraft_info.json", function (data) {
           let options = '<option value="">Select Model</option>';
           data.forEach(item => {
               options += `<option value="${item.short_name}">${item.short_name}</option>`;
           });

           if (forceType === "att") {
               $("#attackingAircraftModels").html(options).show();
           } else {
               $("#defendingAircraftModels").html(options).show();
           }
       });
   }

   $("#attackingForce").change(function () {
       if ($(this).val() === "aircraft") {
           loadAircraftData("att");
       } else {
           $("#attackingAircraftModels, #attackingAircraftDetails").hide();
       }
   });

   $("#defendingForce").change(function () {
       if ($(this).val() === "aircraft") {
           loadAircraftData("def");
       } else {
           $("#defendingAircraftModels, #defendingAircraftDetails").hide();
       }
   });

   $("#attackingAircraftModels").change(function () {
       let model = $(this).val();
       $.getJSON("/static/att_aircraft_info.json", function (data) {
           let selectedData = data.find(item => item.short_name === model);
           if (selectedData) {
               populateDetails(selectedData.unit_combat_power, '#attackingAircraftDetails');
           }
       });
   });

   $("#defendingAircraftModels").change(function () {
       let model = $(this).val();
       $.getJSON("/static/def_aircraft_info.json", function (data) {
           let selectedData = data.find(item => item.short_name === model);
           if (selectedData) {
               populateDetails(selectedData.unit_combat_power, '#defendingAircraftDetails');
           }
       });
   });

   $.getJSON("/static/munitions.json", function (data) {
       let options = '<option value="">Select Munition</option>';
       data.forEach(item => {
           options += `<option value="${item.nomenclature}">${item.nomenclature}</option>`;
       });
       $("#munitionModels").html(options);
   });

   $("#munitionModels").change(function () {
       let nomenclature = $(this).val();
       $.getJSON("/static/munitions.json", function (data) {
           let selectedData = data.find(item => item.nomenclature === nomenclature);
           if (selectedData) {
               populateDetails(selectedData, '#munitionDetails');
           }
       });
   });

   function checkForAirVsAirMods() {
       if ($("#attackingForce").val() === "aircraft" && $("#defendingForce").val() === "aircraft") {
           $.getJSON("/static/air_vs_air_mods.json", function (data) {
               if (data && data.length > 0) { // Checking if we have data
                   populateDetails(data[0], '#airVsAirMods'); // Displaying the first item from the array
               }
           });
       } else {
           $("#airVsAirMods").hide();
       }
   }
   $("#attackingForce, #defendingForce").change(checkForAirVsAirMods);
});

$("#adjudicationForm").submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Helper function to collect input values from a parent div
  function collectData(parentDiv) {
    let obj = {};
    $(parentDiv + ' input').each(function () {
       obj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
    return obj;
  }

  let attacking_force_obj = {
    force: $("#attackingForce").val(),
    short_name: $("#attackingAircraftModels").val(),
    unit_combat_power: collectData('#attackingAircraftDetails')
  };

  let defending_force_obj = {
    force: $("#defendingForce").val(),
    short_name: $("#defendingAircraftModels").val(),
    unit_combat_power: collectData('#defendingAircraftDetails')
  };

  let munitions_obj = {
    model: $("#munitionModels").val(),
    details: collectData('#munitionDetails')
  };

  let mods_obj = collectData('#airVsAirModsDetails');

  let formData = {
    attacking_force_obj: attacking_force_obj,
    defending_force_obj: defending_force_obj,
    munitions_obj: munitions_obj,
    mods_obj: mods_obj
  };

  function displayResults(data) {
    let result = data.result;

    // Basic details
    let html = '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">';
    html += '<thead><tr><th colspan="2">Adjudication Results</th></tr></thead>';
    html += '<tbody>';
    html += `<tr><td>Base Hit Probability</td><td>${result.base_hit_probability}%</td></tr>`;
    html += `<tr><td>Final Hit Probability</td><td>${result.final_hit_probability}%</td></tr>`;
    html += `<tr><td>Outcome</td><td>${result.outcome}</td></tr>`;
    html += `<tr><td>Personnel Status</td><td>${result.personnel_status}</td></tr>`;
    html += `<tr><td>Scenario</td><td>${result.scenario}</td></tr>`;
    html += '</tbody>';
    html += '</table>';

    // Hit Probability Modifiers
    html += '<br><table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">';
    html += '<thead><tr><th colspan="2">Hit Probability Modifiers</th></tr></thead>';
    html += '<tbody>';
    for (let key in result.hit_probability_modifiers) {
    html += `<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${result.hit_probability_modifiers[key]}%</td></tr>`;
    }
    html += '</tbody>';
    html += '</table>';

    // Logs
    html += '<br><table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">';
    html += '<thead><tr><th>Logs</th></tr></thead>';
    html += '<tbody>';
    for (let log of result.logs) {
      html += `<tr><td>${log}</td></tr>`;
    }
    html += '</tbody>';
    html += '</table>';

    // Display the tables in the results div
    $("#results").html(html);
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: '/submit',
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (response) {
    displayResults(response);
    },
    error: function (error) {
       alert("Error submitting form");
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<form id="adjudicationForm" method="post" action="/submit">
   <!-- Attacking Force Form -->
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Attacking Force</legend>
      <select id="attackingForce" name="attackingForce">
         <option value="">Select Force</option>
         <option value="aircraft">Aircraft</option>
         <option value="ship">Ship</option>
         <option value="land">Land Force</option>
      </select>
      <select id="attackingAircraftModels" name="attackingAircraftModels" style="display: none;">
         <!-- Options will be populated dynamically -->
      </select>
      <div id="attackingAircraftDetails" style="display: none;"></div>
   </fieldset>
   <!-- Defending Force Form -->
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Defending Force</legend>
      <select id="defendingForce" name="defendingForce">
         <option value="">Select Force</option>
         <option value="aircraft">Aircraft</option>
         <option value="ship">Ship</option>
         <option value="land">Land Force</option>
      </select>
      <select id="defendingAircraftModels" name="defendingAircraftModels" style="display: none;"></select>
      <div id="defendingAircraftDetails" style="display: none;"></div>
   </fieldset>
   <!-- Munitions Form -->
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Munitions</legend>
      <select id="munitionModels" name="munitionModels"></select>
      <div id="munitionDetails"></div>
   </fieldset>
   <!-- Air vs Air Mods Form -->
   <fieldset id="airVsAirMods" style="display: none;">
      <legend>Air vs Air Mods</legend>
      <div id="airVsAirModsDetails"></div>
   </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" value="Adjudicate">
</form>
<div id="results" style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>
```

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. Please do this in the future as it make it **much** easier to see what is going on.

Comment: I'm not clear.  The function you mention directly calls the same `air_vs_air_mods.json` file every time. Are you saying that you expect this same static file to have different data each time you call it?